# ReportViewer Crashing on Client Machines C#

Tags: c#, wpf, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I am using `ReportViewer` in C# to generate a report of a list of jobs that users can print off. On my machine the `ReportViewer` works without a hitch - I can view and print the generated `Report`.

However, as soon as the user tries to generate a `Report` on their machine the program instantly crashes. Is there something I need to install on the client machine for them to be able to use the `ReportViewer`? Can I integrate it into my program to avoid having to install on multiple machines?

Comment: Check the windows event viewer on the client machine. It should show you the error log for the application. Probably a missing dll.

Comment: @JamesDev Couldn't seem to find a missing dll, it was actually a .jpg missing. Now though the user just gets a black screen, it doesn't crash, they just cant view the report at all. Any help?

Comment: Provide a bit more info. Application runs fine until they run the report? Any errors? Any error in the windows event viewer?